# change delimiter to the multichar delimiter in a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

This is how my data looks,

```
"col1"~"col2"~"col3"
"abcd"~"gsf~t"~"sddd~e~e"
"iob"~"gt~yu"~"ui~uo"
```

I need to change the delimiter from ~ to |@|
this is logic I have used.

```
with open(input_path, 'rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reading_file = csv.reader(f, delimiter='~',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    with codecs.open(output_path,'w', encoding = "utf-8") as outFile:
        delim='|@|'
        for line in reading_file:
            #stripped_line = line.strip()
            temp = list(map(str, line))
            res = delim.join(temp)
            outFile.write(res +"\n")
outFile.close()
```

output:

```
col1|@|col2|@|col3
abcd|@|gsf~t|@|sddd~e~e
iob|@|gt~yu|@|ui~uo
```

This is working really well with some data, but my data is huge around 2gb.
And as my data is having delimiter character in the values, its being treated as delimiter instead of values data, hence resulting more column values than the header count.
This is how the data is splitting up for those rows.

```
col1|@|col2|@|col3
abcd|@|gsf|@|t|@|sddd|@|e|@|e
iob|@|gt|@|yu|@|ui|@|uo
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change your code in a way to replace '"~"' with '|@|'. So basiclly your delimiter is not only '~' but it is '"~"'.